# pandas valueError when using agg function

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am getting myself acquainted with pandas and I have encountered an issue I cannot find an answer to.

I am using the dataset available here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shreyas3108/house-price-prediction/master/kc_house_data.csv

I am then running the function `df.describe()` which outputs everything it should without issue.

Since I am only currently only interested in the min, max and diff of the min/max. I am using the `df.agg` function from pandas to get the min/max of each column by running the following code

```
df.agg([min, max],axis=0)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
    ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg, _level, _axis)
    615         # if we are empty
    616         if not len(results):
--> 617             raise ValueError("no results")
    618 
    619         try:

ValueError: no results
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, when `df.describe()` is able to find the min/max of each column without issue. I have looked for blank and NaN values as well as looking for strings to see if they were producing the problem and my data does not seem to have them.

I would appreciate any pointers to where I am going wrong.

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced. Please add a [mcve] so that we can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not in `df.agg` but in `df` itself. You can call `df` before calling `df.agg` and see if it actually contains data.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and able to done Successfully which you have mentioned in your question.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shreyas3108/house-price-prediction/master/kc_house_data.csv')
df = df.agg([min, max]).T
CLM = ['max', 'min']
df = (df.drop(CLM, axis=1)
         .join(df[CLM].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')))

df = num_df[num_df[CLM].notnull().all(axis=1)]
df['Diff'] = df['max'] - df['min']
df
```

Kindly try this and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Ghanshyam. I ran your code and `num_df` and `data_columns` are not defined.

Comment: I have crrected that, check it now and let me knoe if it works for you.